# delete specific portion of text in Notepad++

Tags: text, notepad++

I need to edit a very large output file of access-list entries. They all contain extra contents I need removed. Example below:

```
access-list outbound extended permit ip host 10.109.40.1 10.3.0.0 255.255.0.0 (hitcnt=0) 0xc93ff6c2 
access-list outbound extended permit ip host 10.109.40.2 10.4.0.0 255.255.0.0 (hitcnt=0) 0x1e305854 
access-list outbound extended permit ip host 10.109.40.3 10.5.0.0 255.255.0.0 (hitcnt=0) 0x46c7e3db
```

I have thousands of lines all needing the same edit. what I need to do is remove everything starting at (hitcnt=0) , preferrably also removing the space before the (hitcnt=0). so i want all output to look like below: I've tried messing around with regex in search/replace, but not having luck. this should be easy, but I'm not finding it. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
access-list outbound extended permit ip host 10.109.40.1 10.3.0.0 255.255.0.0
access-list outbound extended permit ip host 10.109.40.2 10.4.0.0 255.255.0.0
access-list outbound extended permit ip host 10.109.40.3 10.5.0.0 255.255.0.0
```

tried various regex expressions with no success

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\h*\(hitcnt=0\).+$`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\h*         # 0 or more horizontal spaces
\(          # opening parenthesis
hitcnt=0    # literally
\)          # closing prenthesis
.+          # 1 or more any character
$           # end of line
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: wow. that worked great. thank you so much, saved me a ton of manual work! this is a great place. thanks again!!!!!